# Help with Mathematical Induction

Tags: induction

$$1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3=\left[\frac{n(n+1)}2\right]^2$$

so far I have..

$$1^3+2^3+\cdots+k^3+(k+1)^3=\left[\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}2\right]^2$$

then..

$$\left[\frac{k(k+1)}2\right]^2+(k+1)^3=\left[\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}2\right]^2$$

where do I go from here so that the rhs equals the lhs?

Answer (score 1):

Inductive step:
$$\begin{align*}\underbrace{1^3+2^3+\ldots+n^3}_{=\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2}+(n+1)^3&=\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2+(n+1)^3=(n+1)^2\cdot\left(\frac{n^2}{4}+(n+1)\right)=\\&=(n+1)^2\cdot\left(\frac{n^2+4n+4}{4}\right)=(n+1)^2\cdot\left(\frac{(n+2)^2}{2^2}\right)=\\&=\left(\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}\right)^2\end{align*}$$

Comment: alright so on the left hand side I can get up to [k^2(k+1)^2+4(k+1)^3]/4 but I don't understand how the next step becomes (k+1)^2(k^2+4k+4)/4?

Comment: Factor out the term (k+1)^2

Comment: if i factor that term I get k^2(k^2+2k+1) how will that lead to (k^2+4k+4)?

Comment: I see online people have rewritten it so that it becomes (k+1)^2((k^2/4)+k+1) but how is that equivalent to (k+1)^3?

Comment: @Lil Perhaps if you used MathJax to properly write mathematics you could see clearer what you're writing (BTW, why should *anyone* show that something's equivalent to $\;(k+1)^3\;$ ?) .Take a peek at http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Be more careful with the calculations. You did not factor out correctly.